# How to get the STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE, SORT_IN_TEMPDB, IGNORE_DUP_KEY, DROP_EXISTING, ONLINE options of an index from system table?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build the create index script for the existing  indexes of my database. I'm getting information from the `sys.objects,sys.indexes and sys.index_columns.`

I'm trying to build a script like :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [a_Idx] ON [tb_1]
(
    [col_1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But it seems the options `(STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)`

are not in the table sys.indexes. 
Could anyone tell me where I could get these information?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
(STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
 DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)
```

These are default options..which means..if you create an index with below definition..

```
create index nci on dbo.tt(id)
```

all the above options will be included..so you don't need to worry about including them ,unless you wan't to change them..

You also can use this script,if you want to have those options included..

Reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19598.how-to-generate-index-creation-scripts-for-all-tables-in-a-database-using-t-sql.aspx

```
SELECT ' CREATE ' +  
    CASE WHEN I.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END  +   
    I.type_desc COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT +' INDEX ' +    
    I.name  + ' ON '  +   
    Schema_name(T.Schema_id)+'.'+T.name + ' ( ' +  
    KeyColumns + ' )  ' +  
    ISNULL(' INCLUDE ('+IncludedColumns+' ) ','') +  
    ISNULL(' WHERE  '+I.Filter_definition,'') + ' WITH ( ' +  
    CASE WHEN I.is_padded = 1 THEN ' PAD_INDEX = ON ' ELSE ' PAD_INDEX = OFF ' END + ','  +  
    'FILLFACTOR = '+CONVERT(CHAR(5),CASE WHEN I.Fill_factor = 0 THEN 100 ELSE I.Fill_factor END) + ','  +  
    -- default value  
    'SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF '  + ','  +  
    CASE WHEN I.ignore_dup_key = 1 THEN ' IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON ' ELSE ' IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF ' END + ','  +  
    CASE WHEN ST.no_recompute = 0 THEN ' STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF ' ELSE ' STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON ' END + ','  +  
    -- default value   
    ' DROP_EXISTING = ON '  + ','  +  
    -- default value   
    ' ONLINE = OFF '  + ','  +  
   CASE WHEN I.allow_row_locks = 1 THEN ' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON ' ELSE ' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF ' END + ','  +  
   CASE WHEN I.allow_page_locks = 1 THEN ' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ' ELSE ' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF ' END  + ' ) ON [' +  
   DS.name + ' ] '  [CreateIndexScript]  
FROM sys.indexes I    
 JOIN sys.tables T ON T.Object_id = I.Object_id     
 JOIN sys.sysindexes SI ON I.Object_id = SI.id AND I.index_id = SI.indid    
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM (   
    SELECT IC2.object_id , IC2.index_id ,   
        STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + C.name + CASE WHEN MAX(CONVERT(INT,IC1.is_descending_key)) = 1 THEN ' DESC ' ELSE ' ASC ' END 
    FROM sys.index_columns IC1   
    JOIN Sys.columns C    
       ON C.object_id = IC1.object_id    
       AND C.column_id = IC1.column_id    
       AND IC1.is_included_column = 0   
    WHERE IC1.object_id = IC2.object_id    
       AND IC1.index_id = IC2.index_id    
    GROUP BY IC1.object_id,C.name,index_id   
    ORDER BY MAX(IC1.key_ordinal)   
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') KeyColumns    
    FROM sys.index_columns IC2    
    --WHERE IC2.Object_id = object_id('Person.Address') --Comment for all tables   
    GROUP BY IC2.object_id ,IC2.index_id) tmp3 )tmp4    
  ON I.object_id = tmp4.object_id AND I.Index_id = tmp4.index_id   
 JOIN sys.stats ST ON ST.object_id = I.object_id AND ST.stats_id = I.index_id    
 JOIN sys.data_spaces DS ON I.data_space_id=DS.data_space_id    
 JOIN sys.filegroups FG ON I.data_space_id=FG.data_space_id    
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (    
    SELECT IC2.object_id , IC2.index_id ,    
        STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + C.name  
    FROM sys.index_columns IC1    
    JOIN Sys.columns C     
       ON C.object_id = IC1.object_id     
       AND C.column_id = IC1.column_id     
       AND IC1.is_included_column = 1    
    WHERE IC1.object_id = IC2.object_id     
       AND IC1.index_id = IC2.index_id     
    GROUP BY IC1.object_id,C.name,index_id    
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') IncludedColumns     
   FROM sys.index_columns IC2     
   --WHERE IC2.Object_id = object_id('Person.Address') --Comment for all tables    
   GROUP BY IC2.object_id ,IC2.index_id) tmp1    
   WHERE IncludedColumns IS NOT NULL ) tmp2     
ON tmp2.object_id = I.object_id AND tmp2.index_id = I.index_id    
WHERE I.is_primary_key = 0 AND I.is_unique_constraint = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer.I know it's default. But my task is to clone everything from one database to another which are not built by me. I don't know if anyone could modify the source index options one day. So,I don't want to miss these possible feathers.